# Return JSON if given route param

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm working on an Express app, and want to try and get routes which function similar to reddit, in that appending `.json` to pretty much any URL returns JSON rather than the rendered template.

I'm using Jade as my render engine, set through my app config in Express:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', {
  layout: false
});

if (app.get('env') == 'prod') {
  app.enable('view cache');
}
```

When I want to render a page, I use `res.render`:

```
res.render('sometemplatefile', {
  title: 'This is my template',
  data: users
})
```

My routes are defined as standard, with Passport.js middleware:

```
app.get('/someurl', passportConf.isAuthenticated, someController.getSomeURL);
```

I know that I could just add an optional route param like this:

```
app.get('/someurl(/:flag)', passportConf.isAuthenticated, someController.getSomeURL);
```

But then having `if (req.params.flag === 'json') { return res.json(blah) }` inside every route controller is really ugly.

Is it possible to bypass the standard action of `res.render` with middleware or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.handleResopnse = function(req, res, data, template, title) {
        if (req.params.flag === 'json'){
            return res.json(data);
        }
        else{
           res.render(template, {
              'title': title,
              'data': data
           });
        }
    }
}
```

In your `someController.getSomeURL` use

```
res.handleResopnse(req,res,data,template,title);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that takes care of rendering the data, based on the flag :

```
/*
 * Helper function
 */
// Returns data to client, either in template or in JSON object
function sendData(req, res, data) {
    if (req.params.flag === "json") {
        return res.json(data);
    } else {
        return res.render('sometemplatefile', {
           title: 'This is my template',
           data: data.users
        });
    }
};

/*
 * Routes
 */
// Description for someurl
app.get('/someurl', passportConf.isAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    // Get the data needed for this route
    db.fetchData(x, function(data, err) {
       sendData(req, res, data);
    }
});
```